# Wrong results when using training and testing part of bag of words classification in openCV separately

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using bag of word classification example in openCV.

When I use the sample code file (bagofwords_classification.cpp) that contains both training part and testing part, the image classification results are correct.

However, when I separate the code into two sections:

1. Training data and save into xml file.
2. Testing data by loading saved xml file and do classification.

The results are wrong - all results show the same value (1) for all test images.

What is the problem and how I can solve it?